# Django store "get_queryset" in sessions

Tags: django, session, filter, django-views, django-queryset

This post has been rewritten after certain comments below.

Let's say I have two views created, "CheckInsListView" and "CheckOutsListView". These are being filtered on the status = "CI" or status = "CO".

Next would be that I'd like to show the results for a user given date, so I'd make a form "DateSelection" and use a "get_queryset" to match the date and show the results.

What I'm trying to do now, is save the user given date in sessions. When I go to the next view "check-outs" I would like to use the date set in sessions to be used as a filter again.

Unless the user enters a new date, the date from sessions should be used as a filter.

```
#views.py

class CheckInsListView(generic.ListView, FormMixin): 
form_class = DateSelection
model = Delivery
paginate_by = 10
queryset = Delivery.objects.filter(status='CI')
template_name = 'check-ins.html' 

def get_queryset(self):
    checkin_date = super(CheckInsListView, self).get_queryset()

    #Request date from session
    date_session = self.request.session.get('date_session')
    #Retrieve date from user input
    date_user = self.request.GET.get("date_selection")

    #check if session is populated
    if date_session:
        return checkin_date.filter(arrival_date__icontains=date_session)

    #if session is not populated, retrieve date from user input
    elif date_user:
        return checkin_date.filter(arrival_date__icontains=date_user)
        #register user input date_selection in session
        request.session['date_session'] = 'date_user'

    else:
        return checkin_date

class CheckOutsListView(generic.ListView, FormMixin): 
    form_class = DateSelection
    model = Orders
    paginate_by = 10
    queryset = Orders.objects.filter(status='CO')
    template_name = 'check-outs.html'
```

And forms

```
#forms.py

from django import forms

class DateSelection(forms.Form):
date_selection = forms.DateField(label="Date...")
```

I'm not really sure if this is the way to go so if anyone can give me a push in the right direction?

Edit 05/05/2017

Trying to retrieve the session in the template with the following, so i do know the date isn't being saved in the session.

```
{% if request.session.date_session %}
    <h6>Date saved in session</h6>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: In the database? That's what it's for. Or on the client and have it send the information back in next request.

Comment: The session is the ideal place for things like this.

Comment: Alright, so I've read about session. Now trying to save the user given input into session. I've edited the orginal post!

Comment: But what's not working?

Comment: I tried to retrieve the session status in the template but it doesn't show up, Iám assuming this is not the way to go...